# Connecting 2 virtual machines on 2 different computers

Tags: hadoop, vmware, cloudera

I have cloudera installed on virtual machines on 2 different laptops (hp and asus)
now I want to form a hadoop cluster. I saw some answers that suggested to use bridged network but if I use bridged network then VMware cloudera shows no internet connectivity.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer after watching a lot of youtube videos, firstly I am using VMware Workstation 12 Pro, 
In one of the videos I found that VMnet0 was not present when you go to change adapter setting in control panel.

To solve the problem go to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation

In this folder look for the file vmnetcfg.exe run it in administrator mode.

1. click to Restore defaults.
2. if you don't see VMnet0 click on add and
   add VMnet0.
3. set VMnet0 to bridged and then you have a drop down
   indicating bridged to it is by default set to Automatic change it to your wireless driver or ethernet driver of your pc.

here is the video link: https://youtu.be/AsSDXznIhGc